# How to prevent a NServiceBus saga from being started multiple times?

Tags: nservicebus, saga

I want to create a saga which is started by message "Event1" but which will ignore receipt of "duplicate" start messages with the same applicative id (which may result from two or more users hitting a UI button within a short period of time). The documentation seems to suggest that this approach would work:

- Saga declares `IAmStartedByMessages<Event1>`
- Saga configures itself with `ConfigureMapping<Event1>(s => s.SomeID, m => m.SomeID);`
- Handle(Event1 evt) sets a boolean flag when it processes the first message, and falls out of the handler if the flag has already been set.

Will this work?  Will I have a race condition if the subscribers are multithreaded?  If so, how can I achieve the desired behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The race condition happens when two Event1 messages are processed concurrently. The way to prevent two saga instances from being created is by setting a unique constraint on the SomeID column.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  And am I right in assuming that the failure resulting from the unique constraint will cause it to be retried, which would then hit my guard logic with the expected results?